# mechanical oscilator concept to drive electric motor

Tags: motor, transformer, inverter, duty-cycle, dc-transformer

I have been thinking about a project for some time now and am wondering how well it may work.

I would like to make a sleve which could be run by a small electric motor ie from an old cd player or rc car and to hold an 18650 lithium cell and bringing the two leads to make a central connection to two different offset berrings possibly out of an old set of roller blades. These berrings would be set inside a two part sphere made of two insulated plates to make the ac output. this output I would send to a microwave oven transformer expecting a yeild of apx 15x the original voltage or apx 54v. keeping the capacitor in place I would presume would be ideal to stiffen the power to the motor, which is a home furnace blower motor designed to run on standard 110ac. @60hz

my first question is could such a setup work (which would mean a furnace blower that ran on less than 10watts due to an electrical upgrade).I would presume I would need to design a 3d part and have it printed for the job and have little income so wouldnt want to waste money on something which could never work due to some scientific fact I am unaware of.

Second as the motor could potentially rotate the battery at a rate of over 1000rpm  the 60hz standard oscilation would not be aplicable nor presumably stable, but am I wrong in presuming that apx 54v@180hz would be fairly equivalent to 150v@60hz(note i do have apx 20 18650 cells and can easilly scale the power up if needed)

Third ,is there anywhere I could be directed to to learn more about this kind of tinkering science.

My appologies if this post is poorly drafted I only have my phone for internet access at the moment and is how im posting, I have no official training in the general electronics field but am highly interested to learn more. thanks in advance for all advice you may be able to give.

I would note that I do have many other end motors I could use and the actual intention is to make an efficient motor for my bicycle/cart by attaching a smaller rim to the side of my rim to be driven by a belt attached to such motor.

---

Extended resoponse to [Bruce Abbott's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/262013/11683): But im talking about 2amps driving the oscilator and theres no reason I cant push that at 14 or so( with four and still make it easilly interchangable, 4.2v max3.6 min at that each) with a strong oscilation possibly thousands of rmps possibly regaining energy from charging the coil, due to switching being almost as quick as cut off allowing for disipation of its capacitance back to the battery....and its able to have the primary motor spinning faster than the larger motor I want to spin which would be good as a cd spindle will run a couple hrs on one amp...

I would note I have seen microwave oven transformers make quite a spark and welders made from two of them on normal ac...and driving a motor designed to run off 110 I doubt would be wound on wire to handle that kind of load so were talking stepping that down.but the switching speed on a motors coil seems to be ideal to drive it faster and harder....I do have several positioning sensors and the like but want to keep it as  simple as possible.....make a motor that drives a cart.....

im thinking that this will be more of a matter on focusing more on how the electrical force that is being used can be ,by focusing on how quickly the changes can be made  our 60hz mains lines may not be the best to be driving motors if I can do it this way could the effects prove usefull in some way absolutely if this kind of science is not already proven....plus ive heard other things as well that suggest overunity has been achieved and proven but the question I ask you now it there some bit of knowledge you have which clearly establishes that a motor can only be generating x amount of horsepower for x amount of watts provided to it.

sorry to those offended this was ment to be in response to the previous answer. not a new answer and if im answering my own question is the only influence not that a new heading exists and entirely harmless, however your downvote hurts us both to discourage wastefull downvotes which you are not apperently worried about....

> Block quote

Comment: You are wrong in assuming that 54 V at 180 Hz is equivalent to 150 V at 60 Hz in any way. With an efficient motor, controller and mechanical arrangement, your 20 cells could be enough to power an electric bicycle  for an hour or so. This is far from a clear question, but it seems to indicate that you need to study basic physics, electricity and electronics a lot more before you can successfully design anything.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation and grammar. Secondly, what is your actual question? What do you want people to answer? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

> would mean a furnace blower that ran on less than 10watts

No, it wouldn't. The blower motor needs a certain amount of electrical power to work no matter how you create it. Rotating the battery to create AC may be innovative, but it won't magically turn 10W into 500W.

> wouldnt want to waste money on something which could never work due to
>   some scientific fact I am unaware of.

Here are some scientific facts you may not be aware of:-

[Conservation of Energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_energy)

"Energy can neither be created nor destroyed"

[Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy)

"in any natural process there exists an inherent tendency towards the dissipation of useful energy"

At every every step in your conversion process there is some loss of energy - chemical reactions in the battery, the electric motor that rotates the battery, the commutator that converts the DC to AC, the transformer that increases voltage (and decreases current proportionally), even the resistance of the wires - all turn some of that energy into heat that cannot be recovered. The result is that if you put 10W of constant power into an electrical system, less than 10W will come out.

You can store energy in eg. a battery or capacitor at a low rate (low power) and then release it a higher rate, but not continuously. Your device might only need 10W to *rotate* the battery, but that battery still has to be charged up before use.

Do not waste your time trying to create energy that doesn't exist.

Comment: I would also note that I originally indicated this was to drive a bike I believe concerns of driving  a motors coil the same way I would to nuke a potatoe sounds like something I wouldnt want between my legs